# AngularJS - how to hide a button when a text box input is empty?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show, ng-hide, angularjs-ng-show

I have an AngularJS app, and on one of the pages, I have a widget displayed. I have added a button to the widget, which takes the user to the 'Home' page of the app. I have also added a field to the 'Settings' dialog for the widget, which allows the user to specify which page they want to set as the 'Home' page.

This currently all works correctly- if the user has specified a page in the field on the 'Settings' dialog, when they click the 'Home' page, they are taken to the page that they specified. If they have not specified a page in the field in the 'Settings' dialog, they are taken to the 'default' home page.

What I now want to do, is hide the 'Home' button, so that it's not displayed unless the user has actually specified a home page on the 'Settings' dialog.

It is currently displayed in the Widget directive, with the template:

```
template: '<section class="panel panel-frame" ' +
  'data-ng-class="{\'panel-brand\': !inverse(), ' +
  '\'panel-inverse panel-inverse-borderless\': inverse()}">' +
  '<div class="panel-heading" >' +
      '<span data-i18n="{{heading}}"></span>' +
      '<i class="pull-right ti-home" data-ng-click="goHomePage()" /> ' +
      '<data-ng-show="heading">' +
  '</div><ul-grid config="config" rows="tableRows || rows">' +
  '</ul-grid></section>',
```

I tried adding a `ng-hide` & `ng-show` attributes to the button that would show/ hide it depending on whether the field in the 'Settings' dialog in which the user can set the Home page value had a value or not (i.e. whether it was `undefined`, or had a value):

```
template: '<section class="panel panel-frame" ' +
    'data-ng-class="{\'panel-brand\': !inverse(), ' +
    '\'panel-inverse panel-inverse-borderless\': inverse()}">' +
    '<div class="panel-heading" >' +
        '<span data-i18n="{{heading}}"></span>' +
        '<i class="pull-right ti-home" data-ng-click="goHomePage()" ng-hide="widget.customhomepage == undefined" ng-show="widget.customhomepage != undefined" /> ' +
        '<data-ng-show="heading">' +
    '</div><ul-grid config="config" rows="tableRows || rows">' +
    '</ul-grid></section>',
```

Having added these `ng-hide` & `ng-show` attributes to the button, when I now browse to this page, the page loads, but the button is not displayed on the widget... the debug I have in the console is showing that the variable that holds the value put into the text box on the 'Settings' dialog is `undefined`, i.e.

> *undefined*

If I open the 'Settings' dialog, and type the address of a page into the 'customHomePage' field, & click 'Preview', the console then shows the output:

> /pages/userpage2

i.e. the value that I typed into the box.

But the 'Home' button is not displayed on the widget, despite the fact that `widget.customHomePage` (the textbox value) is now not equal to `undefined` (i.e. the condition on which the `ng-show()` should run...).

What am I doing wrong here? Why isn't the 'Home' button displayed even though the `ng-show` expression that should display it clearly evaluates to `true`?

Comment: Is widget.customhomepage defined on the directives scope? i.e in the directives link function it should be scope.widget.customhomepage = true, and not widget.customhomepage = true

Comment: It's defined on the directive's scope with: `customhomepage: '@'`. When using it in the directive's link function, I am referencing it with `$scope.customhomepage`. But it's not a boolean- it's a string... I am trying to use it 'as' a boolean though, i.e. I'm saying "if it's defined (has a value) set the 'hide' attribute of the HTML to 'True', if it's not defined (doesn't have a value), set the 'hide' attribute of the HTML to 'False'.

Comment: The way I'm using it as a boolean is working- that's where I'm getting the console output `undefined` & `/pages/userpage2` from (one from the `if` statement, the other from the `else` statement), it's just that the HTML `ng-hide` & `ng-show` attributes don't appear to be working...

Comment: so there's no widget variable? i.e change ng-hide="widget.customhomepage == undefined" to ng-hide="customhomepage == undefined"